# Is there a regression Model for mixed dataset? (Panel Data x Time Series Data)

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, data-transformation, panel-data

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image: dataset: panel x time series]

As you can see, weekly returns data is time-series data and Factor 1 2 3 are present in panel data form.

I would like to know if there is any regression model that could treat all of them at once or in multiple stages.

What I can think of now is to aggregate time-series data to years to match the time length but ... I think this removes the advantage of the precision of time-series data which I would like to keep ... (Also because I can only get up to 5 to 10 years of panel data which is not a lot I guess?)